# i want to extract this number ex(plate 10X20X30)in separate column(10 20 30)using python pandas by removing(plate)text and(x)character between number

Tags: pandas, dataframe

[data frame][1]

plate 80*800*1700
[reqiured]
plate 80 800 1700
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/64SVy.png

Comment: If my answer helped you, please accept the post.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
df['col'].str.replace('PLATE ','').str.split('X', expand=True)
```

Please make your question more readable.